# postgresql archive_command online change

Tags: postgresql

My customer is using barman and I am trying to replace barman with pgbackrest.
According to the documentation I could replace archive_command online

I am applying following command to change it, it shows "ALTER SYSTEM" after command so it means command successfully worked. It also changed postgresql.auto.conf file according to my command but "show archive_command" still shows barman so I could not use pgbackrest yet

```
postgres=# alter system set archive_command ='pgbackrest --stanza=postgres-11 archive-push %p';
ALTER SYSTEM
postgres=# show archive_command;
           archive_command            
--------------------------------------
 barman-wal-archive 10.46.1.164 pg %p
(1 row)

postgres=# \q
postgres@MWMdb1:/data/postgresql/11/main$ cat postgresql.auto.conf 
# Do not edit this file manually!
# It will be overwritten by the ALTER SYSTEM command.
archive_command = 'pgbackrest --stanza=postgres-11 archive-push %p'
postgres@MWMdb1:/data/postgresql/11/main$
```

So could not find my error, how can I replace archive_command without restart ?

Postgresql Server 11.7@Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding parameters sometimes requires signal the backup to reload configuration before taking affect:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

This reloads the database configuration without restart. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Thanks  
I forgot reload command :(